# Python find matches and count hits

Tags: python, text, match, text-mining

I have a code to go through text files in a folder and look for specific word matches and count those. For example in file 1.txt I have word 'one' mentioned two times. So, my output should be:

1.txt | 2

```
print >>  out, paper + "|" + str(hit_count)
```

Does not return me anything. Maybe str(hit_count) is not the right variable to print?

Any advise? Thanks.

```
        for word in text:
        if re.match("(.*)(one|two)(.*)", word)
            hit_count = hit_count + 1
            print >>  out, paper + "|" + str(hit_count)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but if you are trying to find a substring in a string then take a look at str.count(substring): https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count

Comment: Please add some more details to your question and explain what your goal/desired behaviour is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you don't really need a regex.

```
import glob

#glob.glob the directory to get a list of files - you didn't specify
for fname in file_list:
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
        # if files are very long consider line by line
        # for line in f:
        file_content = f.read()
        count = file_content.count('one')
    print '{0} | {1}'.format(fname, count)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need, but I need to do for more than 200 words.